# Enable to cancel a process until it is finished

Tags: bpmn

I would like to ask how it is possible to model a following situation in BPMN:

Users can submit a request, which they can ***cancel any time until the request is solved***. Once the request is solved, it cannot be cancelled. So if the user cancels the request before it is processed, the process ends without further processing. So until there is no result of the request, it can be cancelled.

*For example until the research paper is published, it can be discarded by its author.*

I model another [example of BPMN process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHF9h.png), which outlines the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This can be modeled using the boundary message intermediate event (interrupting). The message intermediate event catch the cancel message from user and trigger the stop of the process.
[image]